# How to disable the prompt about Debug Perspective mode switching in eclipse programatically?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, perspective

```
@Override
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {

    String editor = layout.getEditorArea();
    layout.setEditorAreaVisible(true);
    layout.addView(VIEW_EXLPORER, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.20f, editor);
    layout.getViewLayout(VIEW_EXLPORER).setCloseable(false);

    IFolderLayout bottom = layout.createFolder("bottom", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.80f, editor);
    bottom.addView(VIEW_PROGRESS);

    bottom.addView(IPageLayout.ID_TASK_LIST);
    bottom.addView(IPageLayout.ID_OUTLINE);
    bottom.addView(IPageLayout.ID_PROBLEM_VIEW);   

    //shows debug view area here        
    layout.addView("org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugView", IPageLayout.LEFT, (float) 0.40, layout.getEditorArea());

}
```

As you see from my code i already have debug view in my custom perspective but eclipse keep promting me to switch to debug perspective when i start debugging automatically which i would like to avoid this programatically since i do now want to confuse my users.

Any way to follow?

Comment: This is configured in the 'Run/Debug > Perspectives' page of the Preferences

Comment: I know that, i thought maybe it can be configured programatically somehow. Is it possible? @greg-449

Comment: You would have to work out what the preference is and set it.

Comment: Also note that the Debug perspective contains many views, not just the debug view - things like 'Variables', 'Breakpoints', 'Expressions', .... The debug view on its own is not very useful.

Comment: Yes even if i added all in my plugin.xml it still wants to switch to debug perspective, and couldnt figure out this.. @greg-449

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`DebugUITools.setLaunchPerspective`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.debug.git/tree/org.eclipse.debug.ui/ui/org/eclipse/debug/ui/DebugUITools.java?h=R4_12_maintenance#n1101) to either let the prompt open your custom perspective instead of the default one or disable the prompt at all.

From its Javadoc:

```
/**
 * Sets the perspective to switch to when a configuration of the given type
 * is launched in the given mode. <code>PERSPECTIVE_NONE</code> indicates no
 * perspective switch should take place. <code>PERSPECTIVE_DEFAULT</code> indicates
 * a default perspective switch should take place, as defined by the associated
 * launch tab group extension.
 *
 * In 3.3 this method is equivalent to calling <code>setLaunchPerspective(ILaunchConfigurationType type, Set modes, ILaunchDelegate delegate, String perspectiveid)</code>,
 * with the parameter 'mode' used in the set modes, and null passed as the delegate
 *
 * @param type launch configuration type
 * @param mode launch mode identifier
 * @param perspective identifier, <code>PERSPECTIVE_NONE</code>, or
 *   <code>PERSPECTIVE_DEFAULT</code>
 * @since 3.0
 */
```